# Calculate abbreviated timezones in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to calculate short timezone codes like AEDT from a UTC timestamp in Athena.

*Amazon Athena* appears to support changing timezones in a region due to daylight savings on different dates of the year.

```
WITH dataset (t, tz) AS (
    VALUES 
    (TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01 03:04:05.321 UTC', 'Australia/Melbourne'), -- converts to +11 (southen hemisphere summer)
    (TIMESTAMP '2001-06-01 03:04:05.321 UTC', 'Australia/Melbourne') -- converts to +10 (southen hemisphere winter)
)
select at_timezone(t, tz) FROM dataset
```

I want to be able to calculate the abbreviated timezone code, based on when in the year the date falls.
eg

- in Jan: **AEDT** (Australian Eastern Daylight Savings Time)
- in June: **AEST** (Australian Eastern Standard Time)

Is this possible within an Athena query?

Comment: What is your end-goal? Using the method you showed will automatically provide the correct timezone based on season. Can you provide an example of what you are wanting to achieve? It isn't obvious what you mean by "calculate the abbreviated timezone code".

Comment: FYI… The 2-4 character pseudo time zones such as `AEDT` (`CST`, `IST`, etc.)  are *not* real time zones. They are not standardized; they are not even unique! Those pseudo zones should be used only for localizing in presentation to the user, not in your logic & data.

Comment: hi @JohnRotenstein. I was looking for the strings 'AEDT', 'AEST' etc. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Hi @BasilBourque. Yes, I understand, and that's exactly what we're using them for, presentation to users. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `format_datetime` from [Java date functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions) with [`z`](https://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) (*"time zone, text, Pacific Standard Time; PST"*) format:

```sql
select format_datetime(at_timezone(t, tz), 'z') FROM dataset
```

In Trino (do not have access to Athena ATM) it gives me following output on your sample data:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| AEDT |
| AEST |

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. Perfect.